# Mixed Bessel Function integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \lambda \left(\sqrt{(z+a)^2+b^2}+\sqrt{(z+c)^2+d^2}~\right)}\mathrm{d}z$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

A tricky integral I have been working on, and probably doesn't have a solution in terms of known functions, is:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}  e^{- \lambda \left(\sqrt{(z+a)^2+b^2}+\sqrt{(z+c)^2+d^2}~\right)}\mathrm{d}z$$ Taken separately the integrals have solutions:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}  e^{- \lambda \left(\sqrt{(z+a)^2+b^2}~\right)}\mathrm{d}z = b~ \mathrm{K}_1 ( \lambda b , \textrm{sinh}^{-1}(a/b) ) $$ where the $K_1$ is an incomplete modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Can anyone think of a way to extend this in the case where there are two square roots in the exponential?

Cheers

Comment: I have a paper (unpublished) precisely on this topic. Drop me a line (laryg@clarkson.edu) to obtain a copy.

Comment: What is incomplete modified Bessel function of the second kind?

Comment: This seems like a good question, perhaps useful both mathematically and in engineering. I wonder if there can be at least some reference, including the (still unpublished?) paper by @larry .